# Display image with width as match parent and height as 200dp without stretching in android

Tags: android

I want to display the image in image view with `height=200dp` and `width=match_parent`.By using height as 200dp and width as match_parent, the image width is same as it is taken.So I have tried android:scaleType="fitXY" but the image is stretching which is not required.How can i display image in ImageView as I want?

Xml:

```
<ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ProfilePicIV"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="170dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/cropView"
                    />
```

This is my xml code.But I am not able to display image as I want.I tried with all scale types.android:scaleType="fitXY" will display as I wanted but with the image stretching.

Comment: Use scaleType _FitCenter_. Also with _android:adjustViewBounds="true"_

Comment: @Piyush Gupta I tried with this.But the width is not changing even though,I have given as match parent.

Comment: Can Anyone fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use scaleType that best suits your picture. `android:scaleType` property for this.

```
1. ImageView.ScaleType      CENTER
Center the image in the view, but perform no scaling. 

2. ImageView.ScaleType      CENTER_CROP
Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding). 

3. ImageView.ScaleType      CENTER_INSIDE
Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding). 

4. ImageView.ScaleType      FIT_CENTER
Scale the image using CENTER. 

5. ImageView.ScaleType      FIT_END
Scale the image using END. 

6. ImageView.ScaleType      FIT_START
Scale the image using START. 

7. ImageView.ScaleType      FIT_XY
Scale the image using FILL. 

8.ImageView.ScaleType   MATRIX
Scale using the image matrix when drawing.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
               <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ProfilePicIV"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/YourImage"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cropView"
                />
```